# Preflight issue with http POST in golang

Tags: http, go, http-headers, cors, preflight

I am using mux package and have this code:

```
func saveConfig(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if origin := r.Header.Get("Origin"); origin != "" {
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)
        fmt.Println("Origin: " + origin)
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization")
    }
    // Stop here if its Preflighted OPTIONS request
    if r.Method == "OPTIONS" {
        return
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(io.LimitReader(r.Body, 1048576))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: %s\n", err)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("JSON body:" + string(body))
    if err := r.Body.Close(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
}
```

It's working fine on IE but chrome  preflight is sending an OPTIONS method and I am getting 404 response back. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 404 probably means it's not finding a handler. Check that the path being requested matches your handler's route.

Comment: Request Header:Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:63342
Referer:http://localhost:63342/Main/app/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36

Comment: Show the code that you use to register the route and the URL entered from the browser.  Also, use http://godoc.org/net/http#MaxBytesReader instead of io.LimitReader.  io.LimitReader will not prevent the server from the entire  request body.

Comment: if I change the method from POST to OPTIONS in the router I am getting status code 200

Comment: func NewRouter() *mux.Router {

 router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
 for _, route := range routes {

  var handler http.Handler

  handler = route.HandlerFunc
  //handler = commonlibrary.Logger(handler, route.Name)

  router.
   Methods(route.Method).
   Path(route.Pattern).
   Name(route.Name).
   Handler(handler)

 }

 return router
}

Comment: Route{
  "saveConfig",
  "POST",
  "/saveConfig",
  saveConfig,
 },

Comment: @BravadaZadada: Here is my Angularjs call :  $http.post('http://localhost:8080/saveConfig', data = JSON.stringify(custconfig))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code registers for POST, but not OPTIONS. One approach is to change your code to the following:

```
func NewRouter() *mux.Router { 
    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true) 
    for _, route := range routes { 
        var handler http.Handler 
        handler = route.HandlerFunc
        handler = commonlibrary.Logger(handler, route.Name) 
        return router.Methods(route.Method, "OPTIONS").Path(route.Pattern).Name(route.Name).Handler(handler)
 }
```

This will add OPTIONS to all handlers. Another approach is to change the Route Method field to `Methods []string` and create the router as:

```
return router.Methods(route.Methods..., "OPTIONS").Path(route.Pattern).Name(route.Name).Handler(handler)
```

This will allow you to add OPTIONS to a subset of the handlers.

Yet another approach is to register a separate handler for OPTIONS:

```
 Route{"saveConfig", "OPTIONS", "/saveConfig", preflight}
```

Comment: I went with the options: Route{"saveConfig", "OPTIONS", "/saveConfig", preflight} Now if I make the call from Angularjs  $http.post('http://localhost:8080/saveConfig', data = JSON.stringify(custconfig)) I am getting  HTTP/1.1 200 OK but it's not calling the POST though. Looks like only Options  is getting called from the clientside

Comment: Here is my preflightcode: func saveConfigPreFlight(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
 if origin := r.Header.Get("Origin"); origin == "http://localhost:8080" {
  w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)
  w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST")
  w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization")
 }
 // Stop here if its Preflighted OPTIONS request
 if r.Method == "OPTIONS" {
  return
 }

 saveConfig(w, r)

}

Comment: removed the saveconfig(w,r) from the preflight handler and the POST is working fine now.   but on the Chrome I still see the error :1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/saveConfig. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access.